# Godot Keyboard Events

Tags: keyboard-events, godot, gdscript

I am studying the Godot Engine and GDScript and I searched on the internet about keyboard events, but I didn't understand. Is there something in Godot like: `on_key_down("keycode")`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use InputEvent to check for specific Keys.

Check out the documentation:  http://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/learning/features/inputs/inputevent.html

Comment: Is there anything specific for key down, key up and just key?

Answer (score 17):

Godot versions 3.0 and up have new input-polling functions that can be used anywhere in your scripts:

- `Input.is_action_pressed(action)` - checks if the action is being pressed
- `Input.is_action_just_pressed(action)` - checks if the action was just pressed
- `Input.is_action_just_released(action)` - checks if the action was just released

Answer (score 8):

There's no official OnKeyUp option, but you can use the `_input(event)` function to receive input when an action is pressed/released:

```
func _input(event):

    if event.is_action_pressed("my_action"):
        # Your code here
    elif event.is_action_released("my_action):
        # Your code here
```

Actions are set in Project Settings > Input Map.

Of course you don't always want to use `_input`, but rather get inputs within the fixed updates. You can use `Input.is_key_pressed()` but there's no `is_key_released()`. In that case you can do this:

```
var was_pressed = 0

func _fixed_process(delta):
    if !Input.is_key_pressed() && was_pressed = 1:
        # Your key is NOT pressed but WAS pressed 1 frame before
        # Code to be executed

    # The rest is just checking whether your key is just pressed
    if Input.is_key_pressed():
        was_pressed = 1
    elif !Input.is_key_pressed():
        was_pressed = 0
```

That's what I've been using. Feel free to inform me if there's a better way to do `OnKeyUp` in Godot.

Answer (score 0):

If you're considering using Input or _Input(event), it's important you go into your project settings and bind your keys.

Answer (score 0):

Press project setting in the toolbar, go to input map and then you can name an action and add any key, mouse or joystick to it. The in the code use:

```
if Input.is_action_just_pressed('Your action name'):
   print('Pressed!')
```

[where is project settings button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzMPG.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to register keys:

```
-is_key_pressed("Enter")
-Input.is_action_pressed(*action*)
```

I would use Input.is_action_pressed() because it allows you to work with the input manager.

Answer (score 0):

There is no _on_key_pressed() function in godot. Instead godot stores certain action e.g.- shoot, walk, jump as Input Maps which can be bound to certain keys (can be more than one).
Then to detect the action in code there are three functions:

1. Input.is_action_just_pressed(NameOfAction) - a single key press
2. Input.is_action_pressed(NameOfAction) - detects if key is being held down
3. Input.is_action_just_pressed(NameOfAction) - detects if key is released

These functions can be used to detect player input in a script

NOTE- there are a bunch of default ui actions already stored in every godot project like ui_up for up arrow. If you want custom actions or inputs then you can go to the Project Settings -> Input Maps and add the actions and add the specific key, mouse click or joystick movement.

SAMPLE PROJECT:

1. Open a new project
2. Go to Project Settings -> Input Maps
3. In the text box type shoot and hit ENTER or click ADD
4. Add the spacebar to this action
5. Add a new scene with a script
6. In the script write-

   ```
   if Input.is_action_pressed("shoot"):
       #Code for shoot mechanic
       pass
   ```